# How to send text to the search box which uses autocomplete in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to book a flight using this site https://www.phptravels.net/

there is a textbox which you can start typing your flight origin airport it gives you autocomplete suggestion which I cannot locate even when I used 'inspect element' on the text box this is the xpath that I found:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select2-drop\"]/div/input")).click();
```

[image]

I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="select2-drop"]/div/input"}
```

any idea how to locate the textbox element?

Comment: Wait for seconds for page load complete before you find the text box.

Comment: I already waited and i can see the page which got the textbox but still i cannot locate the element.

Comment: @tupacshakur the website is a little bit tricky. You can read my answer to find out what exactly happened and don't hesitate to leave a comment there if you don't understand something.

Comment: yeah I did not understand how to locate the element to make it visible. 
of course I have several things to understand:
1. how to locate the element to make it visible?
2. how to select the first option when start typing the name and select the first occurrence of the auto complete suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML of website is a little bit tricky.
Your input `//*[@id='select2-drop']/div/input` is "hidden"(point of view of html and selenium).

You need to click on a specific element: `//*[@id='flights']/form/div[1]` to make it "visible".

So your code need to be like this:

```
//After click on FLIGHTS...

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='flights']/form/div[1]")).click();
Thread.sleep(2*1000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='select2-drop']/div/input")).sendKeys("Moon");
Thread.sleep(2*1000);
```

If you want to write better Selenium code, I recommend you to read about [explicit wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

Using explicit wait your code will look like this:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='flights']/form/div[1]"))).click();

(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='select2-drop']/div/input")).sendKeys("Moon");
```

It looks worse, but is better.

**EDIT 1**

To get the list of suggestions:

```
//after type in input, put a wait to be sure the suggestion list is loaded.

List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='select2-drop']/ul/li/div"));

for(WebElement aux : list) {

    System.out.println(aux.getText());

}
```

Comment: yeah I did not understand how to locate the element to make it visible. of course I have several things to understand: 1. how to locate the element to make it visible? 2. how to select the first option when start typing the name and select the first occurrence of the auto complete suggestion?

Comment: OK , I tried things out and finally understood how to do it.
that was a good site to sharpen selenium webdriver skills!

Comment: What I do try to do is after I finish my search for flights I want to be able to store all the search results into a list by using 'driver.findelements(By.xpath("<STRING>")'
How can I do it? 
@KunLun

Comment: @tupacshakur look at my new edit. If something is unclear and you want to talk about, you can leave a message on chat from link and I will answer when I can(just check it regularly). https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184544/room-for-kunlun-and-tupac-shakur

Answer (score 1):

Below code can be used to select first suggested value in autocomplete search box.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 
20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='select2- 
search']/input[@class='select2-input select2-focused']"))).sendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown);

new WebDriverWait(driver, 
20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='select2- 
search']/input[@class='select2-input select2-focused']"))).sendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: Just pick Logic.

Answer (score 0):

On the webpage `https://www.phptravels.net/` to click on the **FLIGHTS** tab and send a character sequence to the search box example **Pune** you can use the following solution:

```
driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Flights')]"))).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='select2-chosen' and contains(.,'Enter City Or Airport')]")))click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='select2-search']/input[@class='select2-input select2-focused']"))).sendKeys("Pune");
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel but I was referring to the 'flights' tab not the hotels.

Comment: @tupacshakur Check out my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks!
that works as expected but i didn't understand the xpath you put, what is the contains inside the xpath string?
and how can you choose the first suggestion when start typing name of airport?